# PHP and SQL Login - "User Not Found"

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just now getting started with learning how to use SQL databases. I was following a tutorial on youtube; however, it seems I'm having problems connecting to the database. I'm using phpMyAdmin and MySQL in cPanel.

When I test the login page, I enter the info for the user account that I manually set up in phpMyAdmin, but it keeps returning the error, "The username you entered was not found."

What am I doing wrong? I know I'm entering the correct database username and password as well as the correct database name.

Here's my connect.php:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("databasename");

?>
```

Here's my login.php:

```
if ($_POST['loginbtn'])
{
$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($user)
{
    if ($password)
    {
        require("connect.php");

        $password = md5(md5("additional".$password."additional"));

        // echo "$password";

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$user'");
        $numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if (!numrows == 1)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

            $dbid = $row['id'];
            $dbuser = $row['username'];
            $dbpass = $row['password'];
            $dbactive = $row['active'];

            if ($password == $dbpass)
            {
                if ($dbactive == 1)
                {
                    //set session info
                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $dbid;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $dbuser;

                    echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbuser</b>. <a href='./member.php'>Click here</a> to go to the member page.";
                }
                else
                    echo "You must activate your account before you can logon. $form";
            }
            else
                echo "You did not enter the correct password. $form";
        }
        else
            echo "The username you entered was not found. $form";

        mysql_close();
    }
    else
        echo "You must enter your password. $form";
}
else 
    echo "You must enter your username. $form";
}
else
echo $form;

?>
```

Comment: You should call this a *blessing in disguise*. MD5 and deprecated MySQL functions, make for a lethal mixture. Those tutorials should be taken off the web, outright. You may as well throw away your keys and leave the door wide open. Read up on the subject of MD5 http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

Comment: Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). For password storage, use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: You are connecting to the database. But `!numrows == 1` says that if you only returned one result (one row in the query) then say `The username you entered was not found ...` You probably wanted to do the opposite something like `numrows == 1` or `numrows > 0`.

Comment: You have `if (!numrows == 1)` instead of `if (!$numrows == 1)`. The first one is checking if `!'numrows' == 1`, or `define('numrows','anything');if (!numrows == 1)`, while the later is checking the value inside the variable `!$numrows` is `1`. The best would be to do `if (!$numrows)`.

Comment: .... Better yet, it should be `if ($numrows)`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel OP's using `$numrow` with no `s` as per `$numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);`. But I know what you're saying ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nice one!!! Didn't noticed that one too!

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel All the more reasons I didn't put in an "answer" for this one. I very, and I mean **very** rarely put in answers for MD5-related questions.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I wasn't too concerned with security because I didn't have any information to be stolen, and it was just for testing purposes. I was planning on looking into the security aspect after I got the basics down.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You can post all the information here as an answer, in case the OP says that the issue is solved.

Comment: @Cewesler We understand, but using the `mysql_*` functions is a bad omen. You can easily rewrite your code to use `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks Ismael, but I rather you do that, since you did spot those errors, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've posted the answer. Please, check it and edit if you find any inaccuracy.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Thanks for the update Ismael, but TBH, I rather let the OP try it out first. It would be hard for me to say whether it works or not. However, the logic is correct though; that I can say. Let's see what the OP has to say ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's why I said, in the answer, that it is his 'possible problem'. But thank you for checking it.

Comment: You really should find another resource to learn PHP/MySQL. This code is not only hopelessly outdated but it was pretty bad even 10+ years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed by me and @Fred-ii-, your possible problem is in these 2 lines:

```
$numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);
if (!numrows == 1)
```

The first line is fine, but you probably want `$numrows` instead.

The 2nd line is where the problem is.

Currently, your `if` is equivalent to:

```
if( !(defined('numrows') || 'numrows') == 1 )
```

Or more accuratly:

```
if( defined('numrows') )
{
    if( !numrows == 1 )
    {
        // [code here ...]
    }
}
else if( !'numrows' == 1 )
{
    // [same code here ...]
}
```

Which is not what you want. (PHP implicitly converts unknown constants into strings when they aren't defined)

Also, you are checking if the negation of `numrows` is 1. The only way for it to happen is when `numrows` is 0, but you have your code continuing like if it succeeded.

You should use this:

```
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows)
```

Or shorter:

```
if ( mysql_num_rows($query) )
```

---

Why I don't do `$numrows==1`?

Well, any number different than `0` is equivalent to the boolean value `True`, therefore, making that check near useless.
It only helps on readability.